# Matplotlib.plot squiggly lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Am trying to plot the closed price for starbucks. I have parsed the dates and taken the close price. This is the code and the output below:

```py
   df2 = pd.read_csv('sbux.csv', parse_dates = ['date'], index_col= 
   'date')
   df2= df2[['close']]
   plt.plot(df2)
```

[image]

When i try to run it through matplotlib, this is the result i got below.

[image]

I'm not sure if it has to do with the format or something. **I did try to change the format using datetime but it's still returning the same thing**. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried ordering your results by date? You can use:

```
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['date'])
```

to order the values by date so that the trend moves as expected rather than jumping back and forth.

Comment: hello! yes I have tried that too, it didnt seem to work .. the lines were still squiggly

Comment: Maybe try df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['date']

Comment: shoot, i didnt assign the line to a new variable. now it works! Thanks Piccard!